# One-point compactification of disjoint union is homeomorphic to wedge sum of one-point compactifications

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I'm trying to prove the following: Let $x$ and $Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces and $X^{*}$ and $Y^{*}$ be their one-point compactifications. Prove there is a homeomorphism
$$(X \amalg Y)^{*} \cong X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$$

My attempt: Obviously the homeomorphism needs to be the map $f$ such that $(x,0) \mapsto (x,0)$, $(y,1) \mapsto (y,1)$, and $\infty \mapsto \{\infty_{X},\infty_{Y}\}$. This immeditly makes $f$ bijective. My problem is proving continuity of $f$. Notice $U$ is open in $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open where $p:X^{*} \amalg Y^{*} \rightarrow X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ is the quotient map. Now $(X \amalg Y)^{*}$ and $X^{*} \amalg Y^{*}$ are clearly different spaces topologically, so I $p^{-1}(U)$ gives me no useful information to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Some hints: a function from $A$ to $B$, where $A$ is locally compact and $B$ is compact, can be extended to $A^\ast$; continuous bijections are homeomorphisms when the spaces are compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @SteveD where does $\infty$ map to?

Comment: Whoops, I mangled my last comment. Sorry, I was writing it on my phone! Let me try this without so many symbols: if you have a locally compact Hausdorff space, embedded in a compact Hausdorff space,such that the complement is a single point, then that's your one-point compactification. The key ingredient is that the complement of an open set is closed, and closed sets in compact spaces are compact.

Comment: Oh! I feel like a complete idiot now. What you're saying is the following if I'm understanding correctly: We can clearly embed $X \amalg Y$ into $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ and since the difference of these two sets is a single point, namely $\infty$, and $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ is compact, this space must be our one-point compactification of $X \amalg Y$! It's quite an elegant solution.

Comment: Ok sorry I still have a slight issue... I've tried proving the inclusion map (which should serve as an embedding) of $X \amalg Y$ into $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ is continuous. Now I know if I treat $X \amalg Y$ as a subspace of  $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$ then this map will be. But I gave $X \amalg Y$ its usual topology ($U$ is open in $X \amalg Y$ if and only if $U = V \amalg W$ for some open set $V$ in $X$ and $W$ in $Y$). Must I treat $X \amalg Y$ as a subspace? It feels like cheating if I do because one defines $X \vee Y$ (note im not using compatifications here) in terms of $X \amalg Y$...

Comment: Consider the quotient $q:X^\ast\amalg Y^\ast\rightarrow X^\ast\vee Y^\ast$; the domain contains $X\amalg Y$ as a saturated open subset, so $q:X\amalg Y\rightarrow q(X\amalg Y)$ is an injective quotient map: that is, an embedding.

Comment: Ok, but in your comment above you are still considering $X \amalg Y$ as a $\bf{subspace}$ of $X^{*} \amalg Y^{*}$, are you not? So, your embedding is really an embedding of $X \amalg Y$ as a subspace of $X^{*} \amalg Y^{*}$ into $X^{*} \vee Y^{*}$. Yet, arent $X \amalg Y$ with its usual topology and  $X \amalg Y$ with the subspace topology from $X^{*} \amalg Y^{*}$ different spaces? So, this wont help solve the problem? Again my apologies, my understanding of subspaces is quite weak I believe.

Comment: I have to confess, I don't understand what you're saying. If $A$ embeds in $B$ and $C$ embeds in $D$, do you not believe that $A\amalg C$ embeds in $B\amalg D$?

Comment: My apologies, all I was concerned about is that in general the subspace topology is not the same as the topology defined directly on the subset. So, when you get $q$ from $p$ we have to give $X \amalg Y$ the subspace topology of $X^{*} \amalg Y^{*}$, yet this might not be the same as defining the usual topology on $X \amalg Y$ directly. So, for $q$ to be the embedding we want we need to verify these two topologies are the same. In fact, I did this and finished the proof (its not too hard to do). All I was making sure of is that this needs to be verified.